# Laravel, Cache: Change cache value without changing ttl

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

How can I change cache value without changing cache ttl? Is there a way to do that with Laravel Cache facade or should I just make some workaround, like this one:

```
$ttl = 100;

Cache::put('key', [
    'value' => 'foo',
    'created_at' => now(),
], $ttl);

$data = Cache::get('key');

$data['value'] = 'bar';
$newTtl = $ttl - $data['created_at']->diffInSeconds(now());

if ($newTtl > 0) {
    Cache::put('key', $data, $newTtl);
}
```

Comment: There is no way to update a Cache object using the native laravel Cache Facade without resuplying a new TTL. Of course you can do many workarounds. It would be pretty straight forward to add 'ttl' as a key into your object next to value,created_at.

So you can just pass it trough in the next put call. without any calculations on a second point

Comment: Thank you Danny, apriciate you!